# What are villagers type in Minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to know how to differentiate them. Usually I put the purple one in library and stone and the white one as the farmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many types of villagers. Here are some of them:

**Farmers**  [image: A Farmer Villager]
<sub>(source: [cursecdn.com](https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/minecraft.gamepedia.com/thumb/3/3d/Farmer.png/60px-Farmer.png?version=84e6676cbceaeb8bdf482658ff18b7ab))</sub>

These villagers wear the usual brown robe and will occasionally farm the crops in the village. They have an inventory and can collect the crops they harvest.

**Librarians**[image: A Librarian Villager]

These villagers wear white robes and live in houses will bookshelves and are wiling to trade books.

**Priests** [image: A Priest Villager]

The Priest villager lives in the tall cobblestone tower, and wears a nice purple robe.

**Blacksmith**[image: A Blacksmith Villager]

Oh! These are the ones people always hope for! If you see one in a village, there will be a Smithy in the village. There is lava, furnaces and a bonus chest in there that contains nice stuff. He wears a black apron.

**Butcher** [image: A Butcher Villager]

Wearing a white apron, these butchers can sell leather at times.

**Other Stuff**

Lastly, there are baby villagers, which can be obtained by breeding villagers, zombie villagers, which can be turned back into a normal villager. When a villager is struck by lightning, it becomes a Witch, similar to the Charged Creeper.

Answer (score 0):

Well I saw there were more villagers than posted here but I went to install an add on for my minecraft and found out that there are 12 different types of villagers and I'll say them in the order that I found them in
1. Armorer
2. Butcher
3. Cleric
4. Farmer
5. Fisherman
6. Fletcher 
7. Letherworker
8. Librarian
9. Shepherd
10. Tools smith
11. Weapon smith 
12. Zombie villager[image]

Comment: The link I where the images of the villagers are is http://minecraftpocketedition.wikia.com/wiki/Villager

Comment: Maybe you might learn something new there